# Change objects in sculpt mode?

Tags: objects, sculpting, sculpt, select

In zbrush I can select other objects in my scene by alt clicking the object or selecting the object in its layer section. From what I've tried with sculpting in 2.8, If I want something similar I have to enter layout mode, select the new object, then go back into sculpt mode. Selecting a different object in the collections tab, while already in sculpt mode, does not switch to a different object, but is possible in other modes like edit mode. Is there some shortcut I'm missing or is leaving sculpt mode and selecting the another object the only way to change sculptable objects? Is it not possible to do while already in sculpt mode?

Comment: Use `Alt` + `Q`, it works in Blender 3.0.

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

1.- You have to disable "lock object mode", which is in the Edit menu
(if "lock object mode" is enabled you can not select another object besides the active one without leave sculpt mode)

2.- You have to select every object and enter sculpt mode in every one of them

Supplementary:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXNZIIDZC48

Comment: Please read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)